# Build many QLabel and many QLineEdite with a loop cycle

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have to build 40 Qlabels with related QLineEdits.
In order not to write label_n and line_n where n = number many times I use this code
For labels it works correctly because the text is inserted (`sold.setText ("aa" + str (i))`) but I cannot use it for QLineEdit because it doesn't return any value in value.

```
class New_Gest(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):


        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 100, 50, 300))
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle("Aggiornamento Titoli")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        x = 10
        y = 10
        x1 = 40
        y1 = 10
        for i in range(10):
            sold = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
            sold.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(x, y, x1, y1))
            name = "Clabel{}".format(i+1)
            sold.setObjectName(name)
            sold.setText("aa" + str(i))
            y = y + 20
        for i in range(10):
            obj = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QLineEdit,"Clabel{}".format(i+1))
            value = obj.text()
            print(value)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.show()


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = New_Gest()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The ideal would be, for me, to have `label_n = QtWidgets.QLabel (self.centralwidget)` and `line_n = QtWidgets.QLineEdit (self.centralwidget)`,but I do not know how I can do it

Comment: First of all, as already suggested: 1. use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html); 2. do not edit/mimic/merge code generated by pyuic. Then, add widgets to a list (`self.lineEdits = []` outside of the loop, then `self.lineEdits.append(sold)`) so that you can access them programmatically by index. Besides, it's unclear what you mean by "I cannot use it for QLineEdit because it doesn't return any value in value."

Comment: Small parenthesis: if I don't have to, I don't use `designer` because I think it's an overabundant code generator and almost never satisfies my needs. That said, thanks for the tip, it's simple and clean.
I try to explain what I meant. If `sold.setText ("")` has no value, `value = obj.text ()` returns null and so I don't know which QLineEdit I'm on. Thanks to your suggestion I solved this impasse

Comment: You certainly should *not* use the value of the line edit or label to identify an object (what if two line edits have the same value?). You either use the object name, or get the index from the list the object belongs to. About Designer, two fundamental things; 1. the UI doesn't need to be *the actual and final* UI, especially if you need to create widgets dynamically: it could be just the basic structure (including "static" objects that always exist); 2. you should really **not** care about the code it creates; in fact, you should not even open those files, as they are intended as *imports*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this short example

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLineEdit, QGroupBox, QVBoxLayout

UI = QApplication(sys.argv)
        
groupbox = QGroupBox()
groupbox.show()
vbox = QVBoxLayout()
edits = []
for i in range(20):
    edits.append(QLineEdit(str(i)))
    vbox.addWidget(edits[-1])
groupbox.setLayout(vbox)

# To retrieve the values:
for i in range(20):
    print(edits[i].text())

UI.exec()
```

`QLineEdits` are kept in a list, and are added to a vertical box layout `QVBoxLayout`. A group box is set to use this layout, and so we get all the `QLineEdits` vertically on the window.

In most cases, these objects should be stored in a class, in which case you would have something like

```py
class mainwindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui()
        
    def init_ui(self):
        self.show()
        self.q_line_edits = []
```

Comment: Nice. It is simple to adapt to my code. Thank you